# adding mouse movement to a canvas animation

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, mouseevent

i have made a an  animations  in canvas html but now i want to make the origin from where the balls originate move around the canvas according to my mouse position. i want to add mouse event function but i can't seem to get the logic straightand add added to the code , any help would be appreciated !

```js
function runParticles () {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  c = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var particles = {};
  var particleIndex = 0;
  var particleNum = 15;

  // set canvas size
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  // add canvas to body
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);

  // style the canvas
  c.fillStyle = "black";
  c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  function Particle() {
  this.x = canvas.width / 2;
  this.y = canvas.height / 2;
  this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
  this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
  this.gravity = 0.3;
  particleIndex++;
  particles[particleIndex] = this;
  this.id = particleIndex;
  this.life = 0;


  this.maxLife = Math.random() * 30 + 60;


  this.color = "hsla(" + parseInt(Math.random() * 360, 10) + ",90%,60%,0.5";
  }

  Particle.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.x += this.vx;
  this.y += this.vy;


  if (Math.random() < 0.1) {
      this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
      this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
  }

  this.life++;
  if (this.life >= this.maxLife) {
      delete particles[this.id];
  }

  c.fillStyle = this.color;
  //c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 5, 10);
  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(this.x, this.y, 2.5, degToRad(0), degToRad(360));
  c.fill();
  };

  setInterval(function() {
  //normal setting before drawing over canvas w/ black background
  c.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  c.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
  c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (var i = 0; i < particleNum; i++) {
      new Particle();
  }

  // c.globalCompositeOperation = "darken";

  for (var i in particles) {
      particles[i].draw();
  }
  }, 30);
}

function degToRad(deg) {
            var radians = (deg * Math.PI / 180) - Math.PI / 2;
            return radians;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>

<head>
  <title>disturbed</title>

  <script src="toto.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    window.onload = () => runParticles();
  </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I've added a function to detect the mouse position:

```js
function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return { //objeto
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
  }
}
```

2. I've declared a variable m (the mouse).

```js
var m = {x:canvas.width/2,y:canvas.height/2};
```

and I've changed the origin of the particles from `this.x = canvas.width / 2;
this.y = canvas.height / 2;`to  `this.x = m.x; this.y = m.y;`

This is the position when the mouse do not move  over the canvas

3. I've added an event "mousemove". When the mouse move over the canvas it's position change.

```js
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (evt)=>{
  m = oMousePos(canvas, evt);
})
```

I've also added an event "mouseleave". When the mouse leaves the canvas, the mouse goes back in the center.

```js
canvas.addEventListener("mouseleave", (evt)=>{
  m = {x:canvas.width/2,y:canvas.height/2};
})
```

4. Also I've changed the `setInterval` for requestAnimationFrame ( much more efficient ). The code inside is your code.

```js
function runParticles () {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  c = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var particles = {};
  var particleIndex = 0;
  var particleNum = 8;

  // set canvas size
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  
  var m = {x:canvas.width/2,y:canvas.height/2};///////

  // add canvas to body
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);

  // style the canvas
  c.fillStyle = "black";
  c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  function Particle() {
  this.x = m.x;//////////
  this.y = m.y;//////////
  this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
  this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
  this.gravity = 0.3;
  particleIndex++;
  particles[particleIndex] = this;
  this.id = particleIndex;
  this.life = 0;


  this.maxLife = Math.random() * 30 + 60;


  this.color = "hsla(" + parseInt(Math.random() * 360, 10) + ",90%,60%,0.5";
  }

  Particle.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.x += this.vx;
  this.y += this.vy;


  if (Math.random() < 0.1) {
      this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
      this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
  }

  this.life++;
  if (this.life >= this.maxLife) {
      delete particles[this.id];
  }

  c.fillStyle = this.color;
  //c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 5, 10);
  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(this.x, this.y, 2.5, degToRad(0), degToRad(360));
  c.fill();
  };
  
function Draw() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(Draw);
  c.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  c.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
  c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (var i = 0; i < particleNum; i++) {
      new Particle();
  }

  // c.globalCompositeOperation = "darken";

  for (var i in particles) {
      particles[i].draw();
  } 
  }
  
  Draw();
  
  
///////////////////
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (evt)=>{
  m = oMousePos(canvas, evt);
})
canvas.addEventListener("mouseleave", (evt)=>{
  m = {x:canvas.width/2,y:canvas.height/2};
})
///////////////////
   
}

function degToRad(deg) {
            var radians = (deg * Math.PI / 180) - Math.PI / 2;
            return radians;
        }


runParticles();




function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
 return { //objeto
 x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
 y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
  }
}
```

```css
body,canvas{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: this is great but i looking for  mouse click event that will allow me to make them pop where i click

Comment: In this case just use the event "click" instead of "mousemove" and delete the other  event listener